# Xcode right pane (utilities pane) not applicable?

Tags: xcode, storyboard, utilities

I was programming using Swift in Xcode, halfway through when I wanted to edit a button using the utilities pane, I realised it became "Not Applicable". Attributes inspector, Connections inspector, etc all became "Not Applicable", only the Quick Help inspector still shows.

I have selected the button in the Storyboard.

Can anybody help with this?

Attached are screenshots..
[image: Attributes inspector not showing]

[image: Connections inspector not showing]

[image: Only Quick Help inspector shows]

Comment: If none of the solutions work, you can add an `identifier` attribute to the respective element in the .storybuilder file manually. For example, `<segue destination="BYZ-38-t0r" kind="show" identifier="foobar" id="QBP-0i-mUm"/>` gives your segue the identifier of _foobar_. Do not confuse `identifier` with `id`.

Answer (score 83):

Storyboard can't be opened at the start.

1. Open any file (like AppDelegate) but not storyboard.
2. Then close Xcode.
3. Open xcode again.

Works in Xcode 7.2

Comment: This works perfectly fine, this should be accepted answer, and apple should fix this stupid bug.

Comment: Works fine in Xcode Version 9.1 too !!

Not getting, it is bug or smart feature of XCode :)

Comment: Did not work in 9.3 and neither did deleting DerivedData, cleaning the project, etc. Ended up adding an `identifier` attribute to the `<segue>` element by editing the .storybuilder file manually: `<segue destination="BYZ-38-t0r" kind="show" identifier="foobar" id="QBP-0i-mUm"/>`. This gives you the identifier of _foobar_.

Comment: It works and this Xcode bug still exists in Xcode 12.4

Comment: this is still an issue in Xcode 14 beta

Comment: @2022 and still this issue exists in Xcode. This solution works perfectly.

Comment: Thank you Apple, for keeping Xcode that stable for 5 years.

Comment: Still in Xcode 15.0.1. But well, who would expect anythings else from an alpha version ;-)

Answer (score 13):

It also happened to me, I fixed it by deleting the derived data.
Go to Window > Projects, select the project, and delete the derived data

Comment: happened to my Xcode 7.1.1 after some 'successful' git merge; deleting derived data for the project, deleting workspace & project user files, git checkout resolved issue for me.

Comment: i'm also using workspace. also try closing the storyboard, and restarting xcode.

Answer (score 7):

Storyboard -> Viewcontroller -> Control -> (Identity / Attributes / Size / Connections' Inspector) window not works then follow below steps.

```
1. Open any file (like AppDelegate) but not storyboard.
2. Then close xcode.
3. Open xcode again.
```

Works fine in Almost all updated version of Xcode.

Comment: It works perfectly. Thanks a lot, i was stuck from 3 days, You save my day. Bingo. I checked in Xcode 9.0 and also in Xcode 9.1.

Answer (score 5):

First of all, try deleting DerivedData, as mentioned above.

If it doesn't help, open the storyboard or xib file by locating it in the Project Navigator tree. When I use the shortcut <kbd>Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>o</kbd> (Open Quickly dialog) to open the storyboard, then I see Not Applicable in Utiilties pane.

Comment: Opening from project navigator tree is what helped me! If I try to open from Recent Files it doesn't work. So weird...     Tx!

Answer (score 5):

Yes it is a bug in xcode
I have tried cleaning my project, reopened xcode, even changed my derived data location but nothing worked.

**The only thing we have to do is close all the storyboards but should not close xcode. Select any swift file. Then choose the storyboard again. Now you will be able to access the all the things in utilities.**

Answer (score 4):

In Xcode 14, if you are editing a XIB file that is inside of a SPM package and you get "Not Applicable" for selection - what fixes it for me is to select the file in the primary folder navigation in the project. If the xib is open via another means (such as Search), it will show as Not Applicable for any properties you want to edit.

Comment: This actually worked for me. It's a shame that this bug still exists..

Answer (score 3):

This solution still works on xCode 14.2.

I was having the same issue. This is a bug in xCode.

Follow these steps:

1. Close all the storyboards
2. Open a swift file
3. Open the storyboard again

This solution works for me.

Comment: Works for me and is much better than restarting Xcode every time.

Answer (score 2):

In my case was not helping to clean Derived Data. I noticed that I have had opened storyboard in two tabs. So closed active one and opened inactive did the trick for me.

It was with the xCode 7.2.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and I observed that the MyApp.xcodeproj file had some changes after a XCode crash Version 6.3.2 (6D2105).

As I recall instead the App name "MyApp" it was written "project".

Since the clean proposed in the previous answer did not help me, I restored the files from my git repository.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using size class make sure your build settings support the the size class.
Ex: if you are using iPad Portrait
Go to General -> Deployment Info section -> Devices (Universal or iPad)

Answer (score 0):

**tl;dr:** Try selecting the *Base localized* Storyboard file instead of the normal file.

---

I was having this issue recently with **Xcode 9.2**. None of the other tips worked for me. One of my colleagues told me this **solution** which worked:

The **Storyboard** file in my case was **localized**. What I just had to do was *instead* of using the "Settings.storyboard" I had to open up the localized files by clicking the "►" Symbol on the left and then choosing the **"Settings.storyboard (Base)"** file. This fixed it.

Of course, this solution will only apply to your if your Storyboard/XIB file is localized.

Answer (score 0):

Since none of the other answers worked in XCode 9.3, I just edited the XML directly by adding the `identifier="foobar"` attribute to `<segue>` element:

1) Right click the storyboard and mouse over Open As >, then click *Source Code*.

2) <kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>F</kbd> for *segue*, then add an `identifier` (not to be confused with an `id`) so that this:

```
<segue destination="BYZ-38-t0r" kind="show" id="QBP-0i-mUm"/>
```

becomes this:

```
<segue destination="BYZ-38-t0r" kind="show" identifier="foobar" id="QBP-0i-mUm"/>
```

---

This might be unfeasible if you have a lot of segues since it's hard to tell which one is which. For Tab Bar Controllers, they seem to be ordered from left to right.

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure that you are editing in **Main.Storyboard** not in  **Main. Storyboard.Base**.

> because source file does not allow edit change in identity inspector it will work.

1)open project navigator

2)select Main.storyboard file

it was worked for me..try it!

Answer (score 0):

> For me in XCODE 13, that work, just click on `+` button and select-paste

[image]

Answer (score -1):

There's no bug. Just make sure to select the View Controller in the storyboard file. If none is selected, then those tabs should in fact be "not applicable". If you have multiple View Controllers in one storyboard file, then swift won't know which you want to modify.